# Error accessing a view generated with scaffolding in a .NET CORE 3.1 application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a project with .NET CORE 3.1 and SQL Server database.

I have implemented a CRUD with scaffolding for my class Model "Route", but when I go to  https://localhost:44381/Routes appears an arror:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Agalber.Hostel.Backoffice.Models.Agalber_Des2Context' while
> attempting to activate
> 'Agalber.Hostel.Backoffice.Controllers.RoutesController'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired).

Comment: The error means you haven't registered `Agalber_Des2Context` with the DI container. Add an `AddDbContext< Agalber_Des2Context>(...)` call in `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: Thank you, i have added:

services.AddScoped(typeof(Agalber_Des2Context));

And works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue is nedded to add the following line in the ConfigureServices methos of the Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof("Name of class DbContext"));
```

Thank you @Panagiotis Kanavos